# p7EHCscript with tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am currently trying figure out how to load an external script into tinymce. The script is the p7EHCscript that is used to make two divs equal heights based on the height of the larger div.

I need the p7EHC script to be able to do this inside the tinymce editor so the it will look like the final page being created.

My current set up with tinymce is:

```
tinyMCE.init({

            // General options
            mode : "textareas",
            editor_selector : "mceEditor",
            editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor",
            remove_script_host : false,
            convert_urls : false,
            content_css : 'http://localhost/tmtphotography/css/mce.css',

            width: "1030",
            height : "480",

            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "safari, pagebreak, style, layer, table, save, advhr, advimage, advlink, emotions, iespell, inlinepopups, insertdatetime, preview, media, searchreplace, print, contextmenu, paste, directionality, fullscreen, noneditable, visualchars, nonbreaking, xhtmlxtras, template,preview",
            file_browser_callback : "filebrowser",
            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,preview,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage,imgae,media,link",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,

             theme_advanced_font_sizes : "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,24px",
     font_size_style_values : "xx-small,x-small,12pt,medium,large,x-large,xx-large",


            // Skin options
            skin : "o2k7",
            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)


    });
  `
```

Any help in understanding how to go about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to add the scipt as script tag to the document head:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/p7EHCscripts.js"></script>
```

Due to the fact that tinymce is using its own iframe with an own document we need to adress this iframe. Here is the code necessary

```
var iframe_id = 'your_editor_id' + '_ifr'; // place your editor id here+'_ifr'
with(document.getElementById(iframe_id).contentWindow) {

  var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
  if (!h.length) return;
  var scripttag = document.createElement("script");
  scripttag.type = "text/javascript";
  scripttag.src = "http://myserver.com/my_dir1/my_dir2/javascript/p7EHCscripts.js"; // example
  h[0].appendChild ( scripttag );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank  you for the response! I am having a little trouble still. I cannot seem to get it to work. When I run the code given I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null  which refers to with(document.getElementById(iframe_id).contentWindow) {.

Comment: Yes I changed the your_editor_id with the id of my editor. It's StaticPageBody and I also made sure that the Iframe ID would match  StaticPageBody_ifr and it does. Maybe I'm not placing it in the correct place? Sorry javascript is not my strong suite.

Comment: I  got it going! Thank you so much for this script! Had to create the function then run the  oninit : myFunctionName in the API. Once I get enough rep to upvote this I'm going to :-)